Sign In with Apple Vue.js returns 'invalid_request: Invalid redirect_uri.'
async appleClicked() {
  try {
  const clientId = 'com.essama.orbis.mobile'; 
  const redirectUri = 'https://orbis-activities.com'; 

  const authorizationUrl = `https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=name%20email&response_mode=form_post`;

  const popup = window.open(authorizationUrl, 'apple-signin', 'width=600,height=800');
  
  const code = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (popup.closed) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        const query = popup.location.search.substring(1);
        const params = new URLSearchParams(query);
        const code = params.get('code');
        resolve(code);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });

Values :
domain and subdomain : orbis-activities.com
return urls : https://orbis-activities.com
I tried to add/remove https in the redirect url but nothing changes.
Locally or in publication it's the same error.
